# La consulta SQL devuelve todas las filas que tienen un numero distinto a 0 pero no los de valor 0, PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, postgresql

se trata de una consulta con datos de mensajes entre clínicas.

El problema es que, según los días van variando los mensajes y eso genera que algunos días las clínicas con 0 total no figuren en la consulta. (por lo cual queda con distinta cantidad de filas.)

[image: imagen]

He adjuntado una imagen con un boceto en Excel del problema, a la izquierda esta cómo funciona actualmente (devuelve todo menos las clínicas con datos 0) y en la derecha como necesito que quede (que devuelva incluyendo las clínicas con datos 0).

Un dato a tener en cuenta, no soy administrador de la base y es una base muy grande, por lo tanto darle un valor predeterminado de 0 a la fila es prácticamente imposible.

No puedo adjuntar el código literal por un tema de que no es mío, pero me gustaría mas que una respuesta con el código ya hecho, una guía de que puedo buscar, q doc leer, o video ver (puede ser inglés o español) para resolver el problema.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y sin codigo, estructura, ejemplo, datos, no podemos ayudarte.. no, no te deja compartir una imagen, porque no deberias poner una imagen. Deberias poner el codigo, ejemplos, todo... seguro necesitas un left join, o un right join.. o vaya a saber uno que.. como podemos saber, si no sabemos que estas haciendo?

Comment: "código literal por un tema de que no es mío" y esta perfecto, pero puede hacerlo anonimo, y nadie sabra de quien es ( y te puedo asegurar que el query que queres es igual a otros 10000 que ya estan en este sitio)

Comment: Además de lo que te han dicho, de que tienes que revisar la pregunta, en si. A priori lo que muestras se llama `CLINICAS LEFT JOIN DATOS`. Busca simplemente Left Join y con algo simple ya puedes resolver el problema.

Comment: Sin saber como son las tablas o cuales son las condiciones que se están usando, es imposible ayudar. Desgraciadamente, la bola de cristal se descompuso y la perdieron cuando la llevaron a reparar.

Answer (score 0):

(No estoy seguro de haber entendido lo que deseas expresar pero):

No se si se puede hacer lo que pides con una sola consulta, al no existir el registro no lo podrías validar en la consulta, creo que es mejor que hagas una función o un procedimiento donde puedas consultar los datos existentes y luego iterarlos para revisar si falta una clínica y de esa forma tratarlos para agregarle los valores por defecto y retornar esa nueva tabla.